# hive read mongodb bson file

Tags: mongodb, hive

at first:when i **select count(*) from table** it issue :

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.readFully(BasicBSONDecoder.java:65)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.BSONSplitter.getStartingPositionForSplit(BSONSplitter.java:427)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.BSONFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(BSONFileInputFormat.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:68)
    ... 16 more
```

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:

after i set:
**set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2048;**

it issue:

```
Caused by: org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Expected size to be 7169396, not 109.
    at org.bson.BsonBinaryReader$Context.popContext(BsonBinaryReader.java:445)
    at org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.doReadEndDocument(BsonBinaryReader.java:285)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readEndDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:360)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.pipeDocument(AbstractBsonWriter.java:763)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.pipe(AbstractBsonWriter.java:753)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:48)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.BSONSplitter.getStartingPositionForSplit(BSONSplitter.java:427)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.BSONFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(BSONFileInputFormat.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:68)
    ... 16 more
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: From the error, the first one was a `JVM` issue. You're trying to load an entire collection but that doesn't fit in with the available heap. Second one looks to be a schema issue.

Comment: but after i set preduce.map.memory.mb=4096; set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2048; it still error!